# css animations loop timing issues

Tags: css, css-animations

SOLUTION

For 12s animation :

```
.rightleftloop {-moz-animation-delay:0s;}
.rightleftloop2 {-moz-animation-delay:3s;}
.rightleftloop3 {-moz-animation-delay:6s;}
.rightleftloop4 {-moz-animation-delay:9s;}

@-moz-keyframes rightleftloopmz {
0% {-moz-transform: translateX(-500px);}
10% {-moz-transform: translateX(300px);}
25% {-moz-transform: translateX(300px);}
40% {-moz-transform: translateX(-500px);}
100% {-moz-transform: translateX(-500px);}
}
```

PROBLEM

I have four images animating in a loop, sliding in one after another but once all four animations play the loop skips the first animation and loops the 2nd, 3rd and 4th animations. The fist animation only plays when the page is refreshed. If I make changes to the animation delays the images overlap.

```
.rightleftloop, .rightleftloop2, .rightleftloop3, .rightleftloop4 {
position: absolute;
-moz-animation:rightleftloopmz;
-moz-animation-duration:12.0s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.rightleftloop {-moz-animation-delay:0ms;}
.rightleftloop2 {-moz-animation-delay:4000ms;}
.rightleftloop3 {-moz-animation-delay:8000ms;}
.rightleftloop4 {-moz-animation-delay:12000ms;}

@-moz-keyframes rightleftloopmz {
0% {-moz-transform: translateX(-500px);}
15% {-moz-transform: translateX(300px);}
35% {-moz-transform: translateX(300px);}
50% {-moz-transform: translateX(-500px);}
100% {-moz-transform: translateX(-500px);}
}

<div class="rightleftloop"><img src="http://images.sodahead.com/polls/0/0/0/7/5/4/9/9/7/polls_batman_icon735_1455_711105_poll.jpeg"/></div>
<div class="rightleftloop2"><img src="http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2011/202/e/0/superman_icon_4_by_jeremymallin-d417qjg.png"/></div>
<div class="rightleftloop3"><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/UltraBuuf/256/Happy_Hulk.png"/></div>
<div class="rightleftloop4"><img src="http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/189/462/256/comics-thor-icon.png"/></div>
```

The pen has animation code for all browsers :

http://codepen.io/MBM/pen/seIiE

Comment: Actually, the first animation seems to still continue (at least that’s what I’m seeing in Chrome) – but the first image is stuck behind the last one on the same position.

Comment: Strange when I check in chrome I only see the Batman logo once.

Comment: I see Thor with a little bit of the black-yellow border of the Batman logo sticking out to the left and right of his helmet … same in Firefox.

Comment: It makes sense, I think – your animation-duration is 12 seconds, and the delay of your 4th item’s animation is also 12 seconds – that means, when the animation of the 4th item starts, the first item is finished with it’s animation at exactly the same time – and therefor it _starts_ at the very same time again.

Comment: You have basically divided your animation duration of 12 seconds into _three_ intervals of four seconds each – whereas you _should_ have divided it into _four_ intervals (because you have _four_ elements, and want to “distribute” the delay evenly between them) of three seconds each. Set the delays to 0, 3, 6 and 9 seconds – and you will see that it becomes consistent. (Of course the elements will overlap at the rightmost position then – so you will have to figure out another distribution of the percent values inside your keyframe then.)

Comment: So the overlapping was due to the percentages and not the timing! I had split the animations into 3 seconds but was still getting an overlap. Solution added. Thank you for your help.